# ubuntu does not restart after installation

Tags: virtualbox, restart

I am attempting to install Ubuntu 14.04 64-bit version on VirtualBox. When I click on Restart now button on the Installation Complete dialog box (last step in installation), the OS appears to be performing certain checks but stays there for a long time. Does not complete restart process to get to the login screen. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

The prompt asking the user to remote the media sometimes does not come up - [bug #966480](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/casper/+bug/966480)